# Cauchy sequences in the metrics space

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

For any  ${n}\in\mathbb{N}$ put ${s_n}={1}+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n!}$

a) Show that the sequence $(s_n)_{{n}\in\mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy sequence according to the standard metric on $\mathbb Q$

b) For any ${q}\in\mathbb{N}$ show that ${q}!{s}_{q}\mathrm{\in}\mathbb{Z}$ and
$
{0}<q!({e}-{s}_{q})<1$
Where:
$
{e}\mathrm{{=}}\mathop{\sum}\limits_{{n}\mathrm{{=}}{0}}\limits^{\mathrm{\infty}}{\frac{1}{n\mathrm{!}}}
$

C)show that $e$ irrational number and $\mathbb Q$ is not complete set.

I can write the definition of a Cauchy sequence but I don't know to use it to have an convincing answer.
$(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence that means 
$
\mathrm{\forall}\mathrm{\varepsilon}\mathrm{>}{0}{\mathrm{,}}\mathrm{\exists}{n}_{0}\mathrm{\in}{N}{\mathrm{,}}\mathrm{\forall}{n}{\mathrm{,}}{m}\mathrm{{>}}{n}_{0}\hspace{0.33em}{d}{\mathrm{(}}{x}_n\mathrm{,}x_m{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{{<}}\mathrm{\varepsilon}
$

Comment: Do you know what the standard metric on $\mathbb Q$ is?

Comment: Is it the absolute value ?

Comment: Why do you assume anyone would want to do your homework for you?

Comment: I am just asking for hints or ideas cause I found a difficult to do it

Comment: It is. Now follow the hints you posted for yourself. Write out what $|s_n - s_m|$ equals and see what follows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** When the sequence given is a partial sum sequence, it is more convenient to use the following statement for being Cauchy:

$$\forall \epsilon>0,\exists N\in\Bbb{N},\forall n\geq N,\forall p\in\Bbb{N}: \vert x_{n+p}-x_n\vert<\epsilon.$$